# php preg_match and cyrillic letters in iso-8859-1

Tags: php, regex

I'm facing an issue with regex and Cyrillic symbols. I simply trying to read the file, use preg_match and display its content in a dumb function as below:

```
...
$regex = '/"(.*)"/im';
$content = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);

return var_dump($matches[0]);
```

**a sample output:** 35=B 04<8=8AB@8@>20=8O Kaspersky Security Center 10
**string inside the file:** Агент администрирования Kaspersky Security Center 10

I've tried all possible conversions from different encodings, used a function like

```
private function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
         $content = file_get_contents($fn);
          return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
              mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
    }
```

used iconv, mb_convert_encoding and other methods,
and convert the text to UTF-8 during opening the file, nothing seems to work. Any suggestions what could be the issue ?

Comment: ISO 8859-1 doesn't have Cyrillic characters, ISO 8859-5 does.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is also known as **Latin**-1.

Comment: Try [mb_ereg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-match.php). It's for use with multibyte characters

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved, basically the file itself after checking with functions had an encoding of iso8859-2 but the real encoding was UTS-2.